# Does safari/ios support autoplay of http live streams?

Tags: ios, safari, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm a newbie to the whole HLS, M3U8 and autoplay. Does ios support autoplay of http live streaming with audio without any user gesture?

If so are there any sample webpages which I can load in safari on ios? I've used the examples in here https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-examples-sample-streams/ but none of them autoplay. What gives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hls video streaming on iOS/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287226/hls-video-streaming-on-ios-safari)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is trivial. Start with Apple's [Deploying HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) page.

This contains sample HTML for playing the "bip-bop" test stream. Save off that HTML to a file, and in the <video> tag, add autoplay="true". Open this file in Safari. Bang, autoplaying HLS.